# Coefficient in linear regression changes drastically if additional variables are added. Why?

Tags: linear-model, regression-coefficients

```
n <- 100
x2 <- 1 : n
x1 <- .01 * x2 + runif(n, -.1, .1)
y = -x1 + x2 + rnorm(n, sd = .01)
summary(lm(y ~ x1))$coef
```

Coefficients (all significant):
(Intercept): 1.618
x1:          **95.854**

```
summary(lm(y ~ x1 + x2))$coef
```

Coefficients (all significant):
(Intercept): 0.0003683
x1: **-1.0215256**
x2: 1.0001909

How come the coefficients from x1 are so different in the two models? In our lecture we just got the image

but no good explanation. I prefer an intuitive explanation if possible. Thanks.

Comment: There are many, many good and intuitive explanations of this phenomenon here already.  Please search our site using keywords that include combinations of "multiple regression," "significant," "variable", "change", etc. By doing this I quickly found one thread with an explanation at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31841, but there are many others you might want to read, too.

Comment: I had, for 30min. Then I gave up. Maybe I used the wrong search key word.