# Maximising the correlation between vectors vs minimising the angle between them

Tags: correlation, linear-algebra

In this talk http://videolectures.net/lms08_hardoon_scca/ (4:58) David says that maximizing the correlation between vectors can be viewed as minimizing the angle between them, and gives two references: Breiman & Friedman 1985, and Hastie & Tibshirani 1990. The second of these is just their textbook, and the first I can't find, although they had a paper around that time about Generalised Additive Models. Basically I can't find where they discuss this. Is the claim true? Does anyone have a definitive reference?

Comment: I agree.  i think there is also a previous question on this site where this was discussed.

Comment: What happens if the means of the vectors are non-zero - does this no longer hold?

Comment: I think caracal said "centered" variables.  Centering is done so that the vectors come from a common origin for the geometric concept about the angles.  The term presumes that the means are not 0 and that you have estimates of those means that you can use for centering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is often useful to geometrically represent random variables $X_{1}, \ldots, X_{p}$ (theoretical or empirical data) as vectors $\bf{x}_{1}, \ldots, \bf{x}_{p}$ such that their standard deviations $\sigma(X_{i})$ equal their lengths $||\bf{x}_{i}||$, and their correlations $\rho(X_{i}, X_{j})$ equal the cosine of their angles $\angle(\bf{x}_{i}, \bf{x}_{j})$. One can then use graphical illustrations and geometric intuitions to gain statistical insight.

To this end, let $\bf{\Sigma}$ be the $(p \times p)$-covariance matrix of $X_{1}, \ldots, X_{p}$ with rank $k$. Since $\bf{\Sigma}$ is positive semidefinite, we can find a decomposition $\bf{\Sigma} = \bf{B} \bf{B}'$ by defining the $(p \times k)$-matrix $\bf{B} := \bf{G} \bf{D}^{1/2}$, where $\bf{G}$ is the $(p \times k)$-matrix of eigenvectors of $\bf{\Sigma}$ and $\bf{D}$ is the $(k \times k)$-diagonal matrix of corresponding positive eigenvalues.

$\bf{B} \bf{B}'$ is the matrix of dot products of the rows of $\bf{B}$, i.e., $\bf{\Sigma}_{ij} = \langle\bf{B}_{i}, \bf{B}_{j}\rangle = \bf{B}_{i}'\bf{B}_{j}$. Now we get the desired representation in $k$-dimensional space by defining $\bf{x}_{i} := \bf{B}_{i}$, because then we have
$$
||\bf{x}_{i}|| = \sqrt{\langle\bf{x}_{i}, \bf{x}_{i}\rangle} = \sqrt{\bf{\Sigma}_{ii}} = \sigma(X_{i})
$$

And we also have (assuming $||\bf{x}_{i}|| > 0$ and $||\bf{x}_{j}|| > 0$)
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\cos(\angle(\bf{x}_{i}, \bf{x}_{j})) &=& \frac{\langle\bf{x}_{i}, \bf{x}_{j}\rangle}{||\bf{x}_{i}|| \cdot ||\bf{x}_{j}||} = \frac{\langle\bf{x}_{i}, \bf{x}_{j}\rangle}{\sqrt{\langle\bf{x}_{i}, \bf{x}_{i}\rangle} \cdot \sqrt{\langle\bf{x}_{j}, \bf{x}_{j}\rangle}}\\
 &=& \frac{\bf{\Sigma}_{r} \bf{x}_{ir} \bf{x}_{jr}}{\sqrt{\bf{\Sigma}_{r} \bf{x}_{ir}^{2}} \, \sqrt{\bf{\Sigma}_{r} \bf{x}_{jr}^{2}}} = \frac{Cov(X_{i}, X_{j})}{\sigma(X_{i}) \, \sigma(X_{j})}\\
 &=& \rho(X_{i}, X_{j})
\end{array}
$$

Since $\cos(0) = 1$, maximizing the correlation between variables can be viewed as minimizing the angle between their corresponding vectors.

If we have empirical data $n$-vectors $\bf{x}_{i}$ with mean vectors $\bar{\bf{x}}_{i}$, then the representation immediately follows for the corresponding centered variables $\dot{\bf{x}}_{i}$ since $\langle\dot{\bf{x}}_{i}, \dot{\bf{x}}_{j}\rangle = \sum\limits_{r=1}^{n}(\bf{x}_{ir} - \bar{\bf{x}}_{i})(\bf{x}_{jr} - \bar{\bf{x}}_{j}) = n \, Cov(X_{i}, X_{j})$.

So in this case, $\dot{\bf{x}}_{i} / \sqrt{n}$ already is the desired representation - although in $n$-dimensional space, whereas we only need $k \leqslant n$ dimensions in general.

For applications, see e.g. [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/15040/1909) or [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/25650/1909).

Answer (score 6):

Since you ask for a reference, [Statistics methods: the geometric approach](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387975179) explains this and many other properties by visualization in geometric space. For teaching purposes, it can also be useful because you can explain deep concepts to people with a weak background in calculus.

@caracal's answer is very comprehensive. All I will add is a little bit of background. Formally, angles and norms (distances) are defined from a scalar product. So all you need is a scalar product $\langle x ; y \rangle$.

- The norm of a vector $x$ is then defined as $\|x\|^2 = \langle x ; x \rangle$.
- The angle $\theta$ between $x$ and $y$ is such that $\cos \theta = \frac{\langle x ; y \rangle}{\|x\| \cdot \|y\|}$.

What is a scalar product? By definition, it is a function that

1. is linear and symmetric in both of its arguments,
2. such that $\langle x ; x \rangle \geq 0$,
3. and such that $\langle x ; x \rangle = 0$ if and only if $x = 0$.

We easily check that the covariance is a scalar product.

1. $Cov(X + \lambda \cdot Y ; Z) = Cov(X ; Z) + \lambda \cdot Cov(Y ; Z)$, and $Cov(X;Z) = Cov(Z;X)$,
2. $Cov(X ; X) = Var(X) \geq 0$,
3. ... but we don't have $Var(X) = 0 \iff X = 0$.

Actually, a random variable has zero variance if it is equal to a constant $a$. The difficulty is addressed by re-defining the space vector as the random variables, up to an additive constant (we say that two random variables are the same if they differ by a constant). With this new definition, we have a scalar product and we can interpret the coefficient of correlation (second bullet point above) as the cosine between two random variables. It is then obvious that maximizing the correlation is like minimizing the angle.

This all comes from the properties of space vectors, which capture the essential features of geometry in simple formulas.