# Linear Regression - Number of Predictors - Negative Weight

Tags: regression, self-study, multicollinearity

I am trying to prep myself for data science interview & I saw the following question on a forum

You have several variables that are positively correlated with your response, and you think combining all of the variables could give you a good prediction of your response. However, you see that in the multiple linear regression, one of the weights on the predictors is negative. What could be the issue?

My guess is this could be due to multicollinearity, but I am not sure. Can some body help?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: "weight" = "estimated regression coefficient"?

Comment: Also see [Kennedy (2002), "Oh no! I got the wrong sign! What should I do?", Simon Fraser Univ. Dept. Econ. Discussion Papers](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/stuff_for_blog/oh_no_I_got_the_wrong_sign.pdf)

Comment: And [Why ANOVA/regression results change when controlling for another variable](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25605/why-anova-regression-results-change-when-controlling-for-another-variable).