# Retrieving standard deviation from glm and glmer

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, standard-deviation

For my thesis I've conducted several GLM's and GLMM's. Now for my report I need standard deviation values, however the summary tables of my models only produce Std error values.

```
pd_m1 <- glmer(variable ~ male_plumage*sex + X.nestlings + (1|nest_ID), family = "Gamma", data=pd)

Coefficients:
                          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)                0.68318    0.58889   1.160  0.25616   
male_plumagebrownish       0.26249    0.32182   0.816  0.42185   
sexm                      -0.90016    0.24890  -3.617  0.00121 **
X.nestlings                0.26867    0.15925   1.687  0.10310   
male_plumagebrownish:sexm -1.30896    0.76705  -1.706  0.09940 .
```

Is there a way for me to get sd values per factor like in the table above std. error?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Standard error is a standard deviation (in a specific setting).

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error

> The standard error (SE) of a statistic (usually an estimate of a parameter) is the standard deviation of its sampling distribution or an estimate of that standard deviation.

---

For the sake of hypothesis testing you might also consider correlation between the different parameters. When you are adding an interaction term, then this may influence the t-value of main effects.

[why does the same variable have a different slope when incorporated into a linear model with multiple x variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/464170/why-does-the-same-variable-have-a-different-slope-when-incorporated-into-a-linea)