# Consistency of OLS when no intercept

Tags: regression, least-squares, consistency, intercept

Suppose I have a model $y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i + e_i$ but instead I estimate $y_i = \beta_1 x_i + u_i$ using OLS. That is, I ignore the intercept. Working out the algebra, based on [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/159691/regression-without-intercept-deriving-hat-beta-1-in-least-squares-no-matr), we have

$\hat{\beta}_1 = \beta_1 + \beta_0 \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2} +  \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i u_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2} $

I know how to care care of the third term, but can you help me verify if the following is correct?

I can write

$$ \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}  = \frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2} $$

Using the continuous mapping theorem, the numerator converges in probability to $E[x_i]$ and the denominator $E[x_i^2]$.

Suppose I demean the data. Then $E[x_i] = 0$. Does that mean $\hat{\beta}_1$ is consistent even if I ignore the intercept as long as I demean $x_i$ but not $y_i$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intercept is represented in regression just as a predictor with the value of 1 for each observation, the maths works exactly as with the other predictor(s). So the proof of consistency is the same, and has the same assumptions, that is, **the model is correct**. In this case, that is, that the true intercept is zero.

When you demeans $x_i$, you assure that the intercept is truly zero, by construction. So yes, in this case $\hat{\beta}_1$ is consistent, if it is consistent in the model without demeaning and including the intercept.