# R: Test for correlation with a covariate?

Tags: r, correlation, generalized-linear-model, predictor, controlling-for-a-variable

R: I have a linear correlation between two variables x and y, but need to control for a third variable that may be influencing the output. My question is about which test I should/ can use. Can I use a Pearson's correlation and add a covariate? If so, how? Or should I use a GLM with a covariate? How would these approaches differ? I am relatively new to R, so any help on the code would be helpful too. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you can use correlation with a covariate. This is called partial correlation. It produces a (partial) correlation coefficient that is normalized to the [-1, 1] range just like a regular correlation coefficient, except that the covariate is "controlled for" in the analysis -- a concept which is kind of subtle, but some good explanations of what it really means can be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17336/how-exactly-does-one-control-for-other-variables).

One way to get a partial correlation in R is using the `ppcor` package:

```
# install/load 'ppcor' package for its pcor.test() function
if(!require("ppcor")){
  install.packages("ppcor", repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')
  library(ppcor)
}

# make up data
x <- rnorm(50)
y <- rnorm(50)
z <- rnorm(50)

# partial correlation between x and y, controlling for z
pcor.test(x, y, z)
#      estimate   p.value  statistic  n gp  Method
# 1 -0.02288511 0.8752972 -0.1569335 50  1 pearson
```

You also asked whether this differed from using a linear model with a covariate. It doesn't! Check it out:

```
summary(lm(y ~ x + z))
# Call:
# lm(formula = y ~ x + z)
# 
# Residuals:
#      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
# -2.80457 -0.76631 -0.00539  0.64083  2.79261 
# 
# Coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept)  0.05163    0.17006   0.304    0.763
# x           -0.02486    0.15842  -0.157    0.876
# z            0.07098    0.15333   0.463    0.646
# 
# Residual standard error: 1.184 on 47 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.005408,    Adjusted R-squared:  -0.03692 
# F-statistic: 0.1278 on 2 and 47 DF,  p-value: 0.8804
```

Notice that most of the numbers for the "x" row in the `lm()` output match those that we got from `pcor.test()`. The only difference is that the "estimate" for `pcor.test()` is the partial correlation coefficient, while the "estimate" for `lm()` is the slope. (The two estimates happen to be numerically similar here, but they are NOT the same.)

Comment: We are trying to build a permanent repository of high-quality statistical information in the form of questions & answers. We try to avoid overly brief and [link-only answers](/stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) which are subject to link-rot; indeed such answers [may be deleted](http://stats.stackexchange.com/stats.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers). As such this is more of a comment than an answer in its own right. If you're able, could you expand it, perhaps by giving a summary of the information at the link(s). Alternatively, we can convert it into a comment for you.

Comment: @Glen_b I agree this feels more like a comment than an answer, my thought was that I wanted to avoid posting yet another [comment that is actually an answer](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/832/comments-that-are-actually-answers). But if you think this is still better off as a comment, that's fine with me.

Comment: Well, my preference would be to have you expand on the answer so it actually contains some of the information you point to -- then it would be a good answer. [The objection to link only answers is a SE-network-wide policy, as is the objection to answers in comments; the solution is to give answers that also outline the information at the link, and then give the link as reference, support and for additional information.]

Comment: @Glen_b Okay, I'll expand on the answer before going to bed. I do appreciate you taking the time to attend to and enforce issues like this that ultimately make the site a better place.