# Statistical adjustment for regression

Tags: regression, logistic, multiple-regression, poisson-regression, adjustment

I already checked out the answer to this: [enter link description here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/201095/how-to-statistically-adjust-for-variables) It is not a duplicate and that did not answer my question.

I wanted to try to ask a different question regarding a similar problem I've been having (so far I haven't quite found the answer I was looking for).

To give some background info to the problem I'm having:

I'm studying the structural connectivity between brain regions i and j.

The structural connectivity as a function of distance between regions i and j seem to follow a poisson distribution (higher connectivity values for shorter distance between i and j and vice versa).

However, it was noted that for distance values less than 17.4 there is a bias in the model.  The shorter the distance, the higher the connectivity values (so just because two brain regions are close together... they will automatically have a higher structural connectivity).  This may not be a true connection.

So it was suggested that in order to correct this BIAS one would have to adjust the Poisson regression model.

Now, my question is: how do I statistically adjust poisson regression bias?

I came across this reference: [statistical adjustment](https://books.google.ca/books?id=iXtZDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT137&dq=regression%20adjusted%20for%20dependent%20variable&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwip25Tc_8_fAhXqzIMKHRuCA24Q6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=regression%20adjusted%20for%20dependent%20variable&f=false)

And this reference discussed how one could statistically adjust a dependent variable by the following model.

Y(adj)= Yj -bw(Xj-X)

*where:*

*Y(adj) is the adjusted count variable*

*Yj= dependent variable mean before adjustment*

*bw = common regression coefficient*

*Xj=mean of covariate variable for group j*

*X=grand mean of covariate variable*

So should I use this approach to adjust the model? Should I subtract the bias distance from the actual distance in order to correct the structural connectivity strength?

For anymore clarification, there is this paper that I'm referring to:

> We perform our analysis at a region level, where all region pairs are separated by more than 17.4 mm, which based on simulations (not shown), leads to negligible bias due to distance-related false positive connections. We also employ a Poisson regression-based statistical adjustment that yields measures of $SC$ adjusted for the physical distances between region locations. Specifically, we apply a model that assumes that the number of $DTT$ streams $S_{ij}$ connecting regions $i$ and $j$ follows a Poisson distribution with the mean $\mu(S_{ij}|g_{ij})$ dependent on the physical distance $g_{ij}$ between these regions, i.e. $S_{ij}|g_{ij}\sim \mathcal{Pois}(\mu(S_{ij}|g_{ij}))$. Therefore, we estimate and subsequently adjust for the association between the physical distances and the $DTT$ counts using the effect $\alpha_1$ in the log-linear model $\log(\mu(S_{ij}|g_{ij}))=\alpha_0+\alpha_1 g_{ij}$ Henceforth, assume that each $\pi_{ij}$ is adjusted for physical (geometric) distance to reduce the potential impact of false structural connections on our awFC method.

source: [awFC paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22634220)

Comment: Its been 4 years since you posted your question but I am wondering if   you have figured this out.   I've been looking around an answer for the same question. They all talk about the covariate adjustment in the model but none explains how to actually generate covariate adjust values (x).   I'd appreciate to share your findings.