# Meaning of "Logistic regression and Cox proportional hazards regression models were multivariable adjusted for age, gender .." etc

Tags: regression, terminology

From the abstract to the study titled "[Association between the antioxidant uric acid and depression and antidepressant medication use in 96 989 individuals](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28845530)":

> We examined plasma levels of the antioxidant uric acid in 96 989 individuals from two independent cohort studies. **Logistic regression and Cox proportional hazards regression models were multivariable adjusted for** age, gender, alcohol, smoking, income, body mass index, C-reactive protein, hemoglobin, triglycerides, cardiovascular disease, diabetes, and intake of meat and vegetables. Results were performed separately in each study and combined in a meta-analysis.

What is the meaning of this in simple terms?

As I understand, the authors used "logistic regression models" and "Cox proportional hazards regression models", and these models were "multivariable adjusted".

But what does it mean - "multivariable adjusted"? I would like to have a simplified explanation as an aid to translation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the one hand, we don't know what the authors did. So if you want a definitive answer, I'd recommend you ask the authors themselves.

On the other hand, this language is consistent with straight-up logistic or Cox regressions that included all the covariates that were "multivariable adjusted for", plus the ones that were of primary interest. I often see German psychologists use similar language in such a case. Note that the authors are almost certainly not English native speakers, to judge from their names and affiliations.

[Adjusting and controlling for variables is discussed at length here.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/17336/1352)