# How to deal with data from different centers?

Tags: data-transformation, psychometrics

I want to examine the psychometric properties (e.g. internal consistency, factorial validity) of a scale. The data (N=700) comes from 16 different locations. Central means and variances did not differ considerably. However, I wonder, whether I should make adjustments to the data before further analysis. I am not sure whether and if so, how I can possibly apply general procedures for "control of variables" (such as those described here: [How exactly does one “control for other variables”?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17336/how-exactly-does-one-control-for-other-variables)).

Comment: You could use a mixed model with random effects for centers.

Comment: Many thanks for the quick answer and the recommendation! I'll try to do that. I'm not so familiar with it and wonder if I can use the results in the analysis of internal consistency and CFA. But I think I just have to get familiar with it a bit first.