# control for a variable in python

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, python, inference, statsmodels

I am trying to perform multiple linear regression using statsmodels while controlling for one variable but I am not sure how to control for a variable in python.

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
results = smf.ols('y ~ Var1 + Var2', data=df).fit()
```

How can I control for Var2 on this example?

Comment: check out this post https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/17338/285016