# How to decompose the dependent variable in a log log model

Tags: regression, econometrics, interpretation, nonlinear-regression

I am considering the following log log model :

$$
log(y_t) = log(\beta_0) + \sum_{i=1}^{K}\beta_ilog(x_{i,t}) + \sum_{j=K+1}^{L}\beta_jx_{j,t} + log(\epsilon_t)
$$

to explain the sales of a company given several factors. After estimation of the model, I would like to "decompose" the dependent variable (the sales) by computing the contribution of each explanatory variable. Ideally, what I have in mind would be a percentage contribution, the sum of which would be 1, but I don't know how to go about it since I have some variables in log and others not, I don't even know if it's possible. So I would like to have your help on this please.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This doesn't make sense even without logs unless the explanatory variables are orthogonal.  Mathematically, you are asking to compute the "percentage contribution" to one side of a triangle from each of the other two sides.  When that side is the hypotenuse of a right triangle you can do that with the Pythagorean Theorem (provided you are willing to use *squared* values to represent the "contributions"), but otherwise not. This is fundamental to understanding multiple regression, because it implies the meaning of any variable depends on *all the other variables in the model.*

Comment: @whuber Thank you for this comment. You are saying that trying to have a contribution (which implicitly depends on the others explanatory variables) does not make sense since we don't have any "link / relation" between the variables (i.e any link between the side of the triangle) except in a particular case, for the triangle it is clear with Pythagorean theorem but  when talking about the orthogonality in regression I don't see. Could you develop this please ? Don't hesitate to develop the math if you have this in mind I will be happy to learn about this.

Comment: @whuber Putting aside the idea of having a percetange of contribution, in classical linear model I often see contribution as $\beta_i\times x_{i,t}$ but does this make sense ? It implies to fix the value of $x_{i,t}$ ?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/113207/919 for one explanation.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for this link it is well explained and I think I see what you had in mind by talking about orthogonality between explanatory variables which is a strong assumption indeed which is not satisfied in my case..