# Confounding variables in a t-test

Tags: t-test, confounding

Suppose you want to compare a certain score (dependent variables) in two groups A and B (independent variable), to see if one group has significantly better scores. You can run a t-test. Now what if you also have data on two confounding variables (you know there is a correlation between these variables and the score). So for example you know the score, group, and age of each participant, and you know that the age is correlated to the score (the age might be a confounding variables, if the two groups don't have the same age distribution). How would you compare the two groups, and find out whether one has significantly better scores than the other, or not?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17336.  Generally, please see our threads on [tag:multiple-regression].