Why are beta coefficients in the two linear regressions same?
I tried two linear regressions with the same dependent variable $y$. Let us assume that the dependent and independent variables are centered around 0 to avoid the need of intercept.
The first with 2 independent variables $[X_1, X_2]$ and got coefficients $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$.
In the second regression $y$ is regressed against $E_1$ where $E1$ is the residual when $X_2$ is regressed against $X1$ and got coefficient $\beta_1^{'}$
I found that $\beta_1$ = $\beta_1^{'}$.
I tried this for multiple independent variables as well. In the first regression I used $[X_1, X_2, ..., X_{n+1}]$ as independent variables and the next regression I used $[E_1, E_2, ..., E_n]$ where each $E_i$ is the residual of regression of $X_i$ against $X_{n+1}$ and found that coefficients match for all n vectors in both the regressions.
Can someone please help me understand why this is the case. Below is the code I used to test this.
Code
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

n = 100
X = np.random.normal(size=(n, 5))
y = X.sum(axis=1) + np.random.normal(scale=2, size=n)
y = y - y.mean()

print(sm.OLS(y, X).fit().params)

E = np.zeros((n, 4))
for i in range(4):
    E[:, i] = X[:, i] - sm.OLS(X[:, i], X[:, 4]).fit().params * X[:, 4]

print(sm.OLS(y, E).fit().params)

Output
[1.04494552 1.13192292 1.41357081 0.9452581  0.920087  ]
[1.04494552 1.13192292 1.41357081 0.9452581 ]


Hi: I'm pretty sure you are referring to the Frisch-Waugh-Lovell theorem which is well explained in chapter 9 of this link. https://bookdown.org/ts_robinson1994/10EconometricTheorems/10EconometricTheorems.pdf

@mlofton Thanks for the reference. I get the idea of separating the independent vectors into two sets and eliminating one set of vectors by multiplying with the so called annihilator matrix $M$. However, that causes me to do multiply the independent vector $y$ with $M$ as well. The right side in my code is indeed multiplication with $M$. However, in the code above I leave $y$ unchanged. Why then do I get the same coefficients? BTW I did validate in the code that if I do multiply $y$ with $M$ on the left, I again get the same beta coefficients.

See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/113207/919 for a theoretical demonstration.

Hi Ashish: When you multiply by M, all you are doing is creating the residuals so I don't think the example I provided is different from what you are doing. DId you read the link where whuber talks about "matching". That's a better explanation than I could ever come up with. If you understand that, then I think you will understand your results.
