# Dealing with multicollinearity by separating common variance

Tags: r, regression, spss, multicollinearity

On [this page](http://www.chsbs.cmich.edu/fattah/courses/empirical/multicollinearity.html), I read about multiple ways to deal with multicollinearity. I determined that the last method suggested may be best for my purposes. I copied it below:

> Treat the common variance as a separate variable and decontaminate
>   each covariate by regressing them on the others and using the
>   residuals. That is, analyze the common variance as a separate
>   variable.

I do not know how to do it in SPSS or R. If someone could explain how to do it in SPSS or R, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: I'm afraid I don't get this at all, because I cannot understand what a "common variance" would be. Since you say you understand this conceptually, would you mind explaining what the common variance actually is and how you think it would be "analyzed as a separate variable"? BTW, another method on your referenced page (#6) is discussed here at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46185/question-on-how-to-normalize-regression-coefficient.

Comment: Take a set of measures and model them as a function of one underlying latent factor, assuming conditional independence. The variance of the underlying latent factor is that which is shared by  (or common to) the set of measures. How this is helpful for the problem at hand I'm not really sure, but thought I would throw this out there.

Answer (score 1):

One approach that may be what the quote is talking about is to orthogonalize the covariates.  You keep $x_1$ as it is then fit a regression model with $x_2$ as the response and $x1$ as the predictor variable and store the results, call this $x_2^*$, then fit another regression model with $x_3$ as the response and $x_1$ and $x_2^*$ as the predictors and store the residuals from this model, call this variable $x_3^*$, continue until you have done this with all the variables.  These new variables will be orthogonal and not have any covariance problems, use them as the predictors in your final regression with $y$ as the response.

Note that the order of the $x$ variables become very important in this proceedure.  The slope on $x_1$ is the effect of $x_1$ as if it had been the only thing in the model, the slope of $x_2^*$ is the effect of $x_2$ adjusting for $x_1$ but not any of the other variables, etc.

If you change the order of the $x$'s in the process then the interpretations will change as well.

If that is not what is being referred to (it sounds right based on the concept of decontaminate using regression and residuals, but I don't know what they mean by common variance) then we will need more detail, background to be able to help.