# When adjusting for X1, have we adjusted for X2, to the extent that X2 is related to X1?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients

I've just read Elizabeth Stuart's paper on matching methods (http://biostat.jhsph.edu/~estuart/Stuart10.StatSci.pdf), which I find very informative. She discusses propensity score methods and the adjustent for covariates. On page 3 she writes (end of column 1 and beginning of column 2):

> " This assumption is often more reasonable than it may sound at first
>   since matching on or controlling for the observed covariates also
>   matches on or controls for the unobserved covariates, in so much as
>   they are correlated with those that are observed. Thus, the only
>   unobserved covariates of concern are those unrelated to the observed
>   covariates."

I figured that this could also be the case in any other regression model. In other words, when adjusting for a variable, have we also adjusted for other variables that are related to that variable, to the extent that they are related/correlated? I think this is quiet an important question as it has implications for applied research, where access to covariates are often limited, but they are in general related/correlated.

Can I assume that I have adjusted, to a certain extent, for varaibles that are correlated with the ones included in my model?

Comment: You might find some insight in the Mosteller-Tukey explanation of regression and "controlling for ... covariates" as "sequential matching."  I have described this procedure at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46185 and http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/113207.