# Can we solve multiple linear regression using simple linear regression solver?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients

Suppose I have a blackbox function that solves simple linear regression. Can I use this function to solve "multiple" linear regression? 
The blackbox computes the slope and intercept in a simple linear regression model.

Comment: Does the function output residuals? At any rate you can calculate them from the coefficients & original data  - see http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/17410/17230.

Comment: Yes it does (as you said it's obvious). Thanks I will read it.

Comment: You're welcome. "Partialling out" is the key term.

Comment: This text will help as well I think. Yes? http://www.isid.ac.in/~abhiroop/Site/TEACHING_files/Lecture%206.pdf

Comment: I have answered one interpretation of this question--how to estimate the coefficients--in detail at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46185/question-on-how-to-normalize-regression-coefficient/46508#46508 and http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17336/how-exactly-does-one-control-for-other-variables/113207#113207. But if "solve" also includes the *extremely important* aspect of deriving the covariance matrix of the coefficient estimates, then additional work needs to be done. Is that your meaning? If so, then exactly what information does your function output?