# Estimate parameter of correlated regressors using two-step regression

Tags: multiple-regression, unbiased-estimator

Consider the following "true" multiple regression model (observation index omitted for simplicity):

$$ Y = \alpha_{1} + \alpha_{2}X + \alpha_{3}Z + u $$

where $u$ is white noise, normally distributed. **Importantly**, assume $X$ and $Z$ are correlated.

Say I estimate the following "first-step" regression via OLS:

$$ Y = \beta_{1} + \beta_{2}X + e $$

Note that due to the correlation assumption, $\beta_{2}$ is biased. From here, I construct the residuals $\hat{e}$, which can be understood as the "component of $Y$ not explained by $X$". Then, I estimate the "second-step" regression via OLS:

$$\hat{e} = \gamma_{1} + \gamma_{2}Z + v$$

Will $\gamma_{2}$ be an unbiased/consistent estimator of $\alpha_{3}$?

Comment: Why should $\gamma_2$ (a coefficient of $Z$) have anything at all to do with $\alpha_2$ (a coefficient of $X$)?

Comment: I suspect my answer at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/46508/919 might shed some light on what you are doing.

Comment: To be clear, as the link shows it is possible to partial out $X$ from $Z$ (first-stage), and use the uncorrelated part of $Z$ against $Y$ (second-stage) to correctly estimate $\alpha_{3}$. I am aware of that, actually. My question is different. The first stage subtracts from $Y$ the $X$ component (which will be biased due to correlation with $Z$; this is, part of what is taken out of $Y$ will be explained also by $Z$). My intuition is that the answer to my question is no, but I want a more formal proof, if possible.

Comment: The material I directed you to shows that if you also partial $X$ out of $Z$, then in the last step you will obtain the correct multiple regression coefficient estimate.  But, since by construction $\hat e$ is orthogonal to $X$, that's not actually necessary.

Comment: I see. Maybe I should be more precise. I found this two-step method in a paper, and I want to evaluate it's robustness. So my question is really about whether the estimation is consistent or not.