# Hierarchical and sequential regression

Tags: regression, linear, multilevel-analysis

I performed a hierarchical multiple regression to study the effect of different variables, above and beyond the apriori selected more important variables. The R script used to perform this regression is listed below.

```
Data <- read.csv("~/Desktop/data.csv", header=T,quote="")
Data$catVar.f <- factor(HMRdata$catVar)
HRModel1 <- lm(responseV ~ catVar.f, Data)
HRModel2 <- lm(responseV ~ catVar.f + v1, Data)
HRModel3 <- lm(responseV ~ catVar.f + v1+ v2, Data)
HRModel4 <- lm(responseV ~ catVar.f + v1 + v2 + v3, Data)
summary (HRModel1)
summary (HRModel2)
summary (HRModel3)
summary (HRModel4)
anova (HRModel1, HRModel2, HRModel3, HRModel4)
```

My supervisor thought that the collinearity within the variables may pose a problem, and so asked to me perform a similar method called sequential regression, in which, instead of adding the new variables in the later regression analyses, I added residuals of these variables regressed against the previous, more important variables. The R script for this regression method is listed below –

```
RModel1 <- lm(v1 ~ catVar.f, Data, na.action = na.exclude)
v1residuals <- resid(RModel1)
RModel2 <- lm(v2 ~ catVar.f + v1residuals, Data, na.action = na.exclude)
v2residuals <- resid(RModel2)
RModel3 <- lm(v3 ~ catVar.f + v1residuals + v2residuals, Data, na.action = na.exclude)
v3residuals <- resid(RModel3)
SRModel1 <- lm(responseV ~ catVar.f, Data)
SRModel2 <- lm(responseV ~ catVar.f + v1residuals, Data)
SRModel3 <- lm(responseV ~ catVar.f + v1residuals + v2residuals, Data)
SRModel4 <- lm(responseV ~ catVar.f + v1residuals + v2residuals + v3residuals, Data)
summary (SRModel1)
summary (SRModel2)
summary (SRModel3)
summary (SRModel4)
anova (SRModel1, SRModel2, SRModel3, SRModel4)
```

To my surprise, the outputs (for summary and anova functions) of both the regression methods are exactly the same. Since I do not know the statistical principals behind these methods, I cannot figure out the reason for the same outputs. Can somebody please explain why both methods gave the same outputs? Also, is there any mistake in my approach?

EDIT - outputs from anova

Hierarchical Regression output

```
Model 1: responseV ~ catVar.f
Model 2: responseV ~ catVar.f + v1  
Model 3: responseV ~ catVar.f + v1 + v2
Model 4: responseV ~ catVar.f + v1 + v2 + v3 + v4
Model 5: responseV ~ catVar.f + v1 + v2 + v3 + v4 + v5 + v6 +v7 + v8        

Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq        F    Pr(>F)    
1     53 7324.2
2     52 2663.8  1    4660.3 111.3874 9.347e-14 ***
3     51 2057.7  1     606.1  14.4874 0.0004238 ***
4     49 1968.2  2      89.5   1.0699 0.3516141
5     45 1882.8  4      85.4   0.5103 0.7283774
```

Sequential regression output

```
Model 1: responseV ~ catVar.f
Model 2: responseV ~ catVar.f + v1  residuals
Model 3: responseV ~ catVar.f + v1residuals + v2residuals
Model 4: responseV ~ catVar.f + v1residuals + v2residuals + v3residuals + v4residuals
Model 5: responseV ~ catVar.f + v1residuals + v2residuals + v3residuals + v4residuals + v5residuals + v6residuals +v7residuals + v8residuals

  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq        F    Pr(>F)    
1     53 7324.2 
2     52 2663.8  1    4660.3 111.3874 9.347e-14 ***
3     51 2057.7  1     606.1  14.4874 0.0004238 ***
4     49 1968.2  2      89.5   1.0699 0.3516141
5     45 1882.8  4      85.4   0.5103 0.7283774
```

Comment: I have added the outputs for the anova functions. The discrepancy between script and output (i.e. 4 vs 5 models, and less variables in script than output) is because I simplified the script before posting here, but the principle is the same.

Comment: You should not be surprised! Your Q is answered here:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46185/question-on-how-to-normalize-regression-coefficient/46508#46508   (maybe a duplicate?)