# Why is $\mathbf\Phi^{\top}\mathbf\Phi$ a positive definite matrix?

Tags: normal-distribution, likelihood, covariance-matrix, eigenvalues, hessian

I had this question when reading section 3.5.3 on page 170 of "Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning" written by Christopher M. Bishop:

[image]

Here $\mathbf\Phi$ represents the design matrix and $\beta$ is precision which is positive.

My question is: why is $\mathbf\Phi^\top\mathbf\Phi$ a positive definite matrix?

I tried to prove it by showing that the error function defined in equation (3.80) of the same book has a local minimum at $\mathbf m_N$. But I don't have the luck (I can prove $\nabla E$ is zero at $\mathbf m_N$, but I cannot show further that $\mathbf m_N$ is necessarily a local minimum)  and, even if it is the case, I cannot establish positive definiteness of $\mathbf\Phi^\top\mathbf\Phi$ from that of $\mathbf A$. So, can you please help me prove that $\mathbf\Phi^\top\mathbf\Phi$ is positive definite? Thanks a lot.

**Edit**: The columns of the design matrix $\mathbf\Phi$ are linearly independent almost surely, because the elements of this matrix are (functions of) random variables. This condition is essential in excluding positive semi-definiteness. As an aside, it is usually assumed that the number of samples $N$ is larger than the number of basis functions $M$.

Comment: Can you say more about $\Phi$? In general, for a real-valued matrix $X$, we have that $X^T X$ is positive **semi**-definite: $$
z^T X^T Xz = \| X z \|_2^2 \ge 0
$$ for some vector $z \neq 0$. The intuition is that the sums of squares of real numbers must be non-negative. So there must be some additional property to $\Phi$. As a hint, the key is to work out what property $\Phi$ has to make the claim true.

Comment: The product of X transpose and X is a gram matrix https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_matrix. You can prove these matrices are positive definite.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note we have
$$
v^\top \left(\Phi^\top\Phi\right) v = \left(v^\top \Phi^\top\right) \left(\Phi v\right) 
 = \left(\Phi v \right)^\top \left(\Phi v\right) = \|\Phi v \|_2^2 \geq 0
$$
for all $\Phi \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times M}, v \in \mathbb{R}^M; M, N \in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$. This establishes the general positive-*semi*definiteness of $\Phi^\top\Phi$.
Moreover,
$$
\|\Phi v \|_2^2 = 0 \iff \|\Phi v \|_2 = 0 \iff \Phi v \ = 0_{\mathbb{R}^N},
$$
which means that $\Phi^\top\Phi$ and hence $\beta\Phi^\top\Phi$ (with $\beta \in \mathbb{R_{>0}}$) is positive-*definite* if (and only if) the *columns of $\Phi$ are linearly independent*.

Comment: semi-definite...

Comment: @usεr11852 No, positive definite. If $\Phi$ has full column rank then $\Phi v \neq 0_{ \mathbb{R}^N}$ and thus $v^\top \left(\Phi^\top\Phi\right) v = \|\Phi v \|_2^2  > 0$ for all $v \in \mathbb{R}^M \setminus \left\{ 0_{ \mathbb{R}^M} \right\}$

Comment: You don't say that about $\Phi$ in your answer nor is mentioned in the OP's question.

Comment: @usεr11852 I *do* say that in my answer: "is positive definite if the columns of $\Phi$ are linearly independent"

Comment: This answer might be clearer if you state up front that the claim in the question is not true *in general*, unless we make an additional assumption about $\Phi$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the condition that the columns of $\math\Phi$ should be linearly independent. This is true almost surely because the elements of the design matrix are (functions of) random variables.

Comment: @Sycorax made an edit. Hope it's clearer now.

Comment: @zzzhhh yes. They are linearly independent _almost surely._

Comment: The post looks complete and concise, @statmerkur.

Comment: @User1865345 Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Thank you for the edits.

Answer (score 8):

**Observation $1.$** *A symmetric matrix $\mathbf A^\mathsf T\mathbf A$ is positive semi-definite.*

Note that

$$\mathbf v^\mathsf T\mathbf A^\mathsf T\mathbf A\mathbf v= (\mathbf A\mathbf v)^\mathsf T\cdot ( \mathbf A\mathbf v)\geq 0.\tag 1$$

Also, $\mathbf A\mathbf v=\mathbf 0$ implies $\mathbf A^\mathsf T\mathbf A$ being positive definite when $\mathcal N(\mathbf A) =\{\mathbf 0\}$, i.e., when $\mathbf A$ has linearly independent columns.