# How To Get Intercept with Moore-Penrose Pseudo Inverse

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I am doing multiple linear regression.   I was directed to this question on how to solve MLR as a sequence of simple linear regressions, [Question on how to normalize regression coefficient](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46185/question-on-how-to-normalize-regression-coefficient/46508#46508)   and I understand this result.

However I have also been told that Moore-Penrose Pseudo Inverse can be used for MLR.  In doing so I see that it does indeed give the least squares result for a set of linear equations.   However I can't figure out how to use it for linear regression if I have a y intercept that is non-zero.

The Moore-Penrose Equation that I understand, which is ( (A' * A)^-1 * A' ) * y seems to force a regression through the origin.   Is there a way to use it and then calculate an intercept ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The intercept term can be viewed as the coefficient of an independent variable that is always one. Therefore, adding a column of ones to the matrix $A$ will result in the intercept term surfacing at the corresponding position.