# Differences between a sequence of simple linear regressions vs a single multiple linear regression

Tags: multiple-regression

I'd like help considering two different strategies in performing my regression.

**Strategy 1:**

model the output `y` as a linear combination of input variables `x1` through `x3`:

`fit = lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3)`

**Strategy 2:**

model the output `y` with a linear relationship single input variable `x1`, and then model the residual of that through `x2` etc:

```
firstFit = lm(y ~ x1)
firstResidual = y - predict(firstFit)
secondFit <- lm(firstResidual ~ x2 + 0) # Only one intercept
secondResidual = firstResidual - predict(secondFit)
thirdFit <- lm(secondResidual ~ x3 + 0) # Only one intercept
```

**Questions:**

1. What are the differences between these two strategies?
2. Can I expect that the "quality" of the coefficients in Strategy 1 to be uniform across `X`, and in Strategy 2 to not be?
3. Strategy 1 seems generally the way to go, what would be a circumstance where Strategy 2 would be better?
4. If I believe that the "truth" is that `y` is the output of a nested set of functions:
   `y = f1(x1, f2(x2, f3(x3)))`, 
   would Strategy 2 be an appropriate way to model the system?

Comment: This situation is thoroughly explained--with examples, figures, and code--at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/46508/919.  The theory is described again at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/113207/919.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The second strategy is the same linear model, but with a different/inferior estimation procedure.**

---

Let's look at the sequential approach more closely, with two covariates $X_1$ and $X_2$. After regressing $Y$ on $X_1$, we have:

$$\hat Y = b_0 + b_1X_1$$

Now, you want to regress the residuals on $X_2$. Thus, the model we are assuming is,

$$Y - \hat Y = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 X_2 + \epsilon$$

Or equivalently,

\begin{align*}
Y &= \hat Y + \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 X_2 + \epsilon \\
&= (b_0 + \alpha_0) + b_1 X_1 + \alpha_1 X_2 + \epsilon 
\end{align*}

It seems to me, that the sequential approach is more or less a roundabout way, to getting the same linear model, with a different estimation procedure.

1. Strategy 1
   $$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_1 + \beta_2X_2 + \epsilon$$
2. Strategy 2
   $$Y = (b_0 + \alpha_0) + b_1 X_1 + \alpha_1 X_2 + \epsilon$$

Since the **OLS estimators are the Best Linear Unbiased Estimators** for normally distributed $\epsilon$, it's hard to imagine that the second approach could offer any improvement.

---

### Simulations

I simulated $n=100$ data points from the model $Y = 1 + 2X_1 - X_2 + \epsilon$, where $\epsilon \sim N(0, 1)$. Repeating the simulation $10,000$ times, we can consider sampling distributions for the OLS and sequential procedures.

[image]

The estimation of $\beta_3$ is comparable for both cases, but the OLS estimation procedure leads to more precise estimation of $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$.

Comment: +1 I'll just add that Strategy 2 is known as [Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) and generally avoided because of numeric instability.

Comment: Note that those two approaches only return the same estimates if X_1 and X_2 do not share the same variance with Y. It would be nice to see a discussion of the same question in this general case.