# Robust method to extract "pure" part of a variable

Tags: regression, machine-learning, correlation

I am trying to perform a multi linear regression model:

$$y_i = β_0 + β_1x_{i1} + β_2x_{i2} +... + β_px_{ip} + ε_i$$

where $$x_{i1}, x_{i2}, ..., x_{ip}$$ are highly correlated with each other (VIFs can be as low as 5 and high as 30).

I am just wondering if there exists a procedure with the following properties:

**1) extracts the pure part of each independent variable, where pure is defined as a part of the variable which is uncorrelated with other variables.**

**2) the pure part and the original variable should be similar to each other, whether similar is defined as moments such as mean and variance and correlation coefficient (ideally >0.90)**

Comment: There really can't be such a method.  If you have two variables in your model whose correlation is 90%, how would you extract two new variables with the stated properties?  It would be impossible!

Comment: @MatthewDrury Well, that's why I asked because I couldn't find a suitable method..

Comment: Right!  So, given that such a method can't really exist, what compromises would you like to make on your conditions?

Comment: It sounds like you might be asking about a procedure I have described at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/46508/919.  Could that be it?