# Why does multiple regression equation make sense?

Tags: multiple-regression

the equation of multiple regression here can be interpreted as y = b1x1 + b2x2 + … + bnxn + c.

where bn is the slope of the regression , xn is the independent variable

I understand that if we were to do the simple regression which involves like 2 independent variables we can calculate a line with a certain slope at a specific y-intercept to be as close as as possible from the training data we have on the graph and having the least amount of errors. From what I heard Multiple regression is an extension of simple regression but I can't quite grasp Multiple regression equation. Can someone explain it's intuition?

Comment: As a very quick answer, multiple regression constructs a canonical variable that gives the best OLS solution for the data - you can rewrite $y = \beta_1*x_1 + \beta_2*x_2 $ as $y = (\beta_1 + \beta_2)*(x_1 | x_2 + x_2 | x_1)$, which makes it easy to see that multiple regression is just simple regression on a linear combination of the predictor variables.

Comment: @rishi-k Watch out for the distributive property!

Comment: Ah, good point - I suppose that's where the fact that the xs in the canonical variable have the other regressors partialed out comes in.

Comment: And, actually, it's not so simple as $(\beta_1 + \beta_2)$, but indeed multiple regression can be expressed as simple linear regression of a canonical variable. See: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46185/question-on-how-to-normalize-regression-coefficient/46508#46508

Comment: There is so much to multiple regression that many long textbooks have been written on the subject.  You therefore might find it helpful to read over some of [our highest-voted threads about it](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiple-regression?tab=Votes).

Comment: Can you see how a plane in 3d space is similar to a line on 2d space? If not then you need to work on this first before thinking of regression

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively you can think of multiple regression as extending the two-dimensional "draw a line through the cloud of points" into 3 or more dimensions.

So in a simple linear regression with *one* independent variable (X) and one dependent variable Y, we can imagine an X-Y plot, with a Y axis and an X axis. Each observation in the dataset is a point (x,y) somewhere in that plane. If we plot them all they create a cloud. We draw a line

$y=\beta_0+\beta_1x$

through that line, and we use some matrix algebra to find the specific values of $\beta_0$ (the intercept) and $\beta_0$ (the slope) that minimize the sum of the squared errors between the Y values predicted by the line and the actual Y values of the point.

If we wanted to add a second independent variable Z to the equation then now we have a three dimensional space, with X, Y and Z coordinates. We can still plot each observation in that space, producing a 3D cloud of points. Now our goal is to find the two dimensional *plane* that goes through the "center" of the cloud. Of course a plane floating in 3d space doesn't have just one slope: it has two *partial* slopes, one (call it $\beta_1$) showing how much the plane tilts in the Y direction when Z stays constant and X increases, and one (call it $\beta_2$) showing how much Y increases when Z goes up by one and X stays the same. The equation of that plane is

$y=\beta_0+\beta_1x+\beta_2z$

This is a lot harder to visualize but we can use the same matrix algebra to find the "best" values for the various beta coefficients (the ones that minimize the sum of squared errors). And even if we add more variables, going into 4 or more dimensions, the matrix algebra still works, even though it's utterly impossible to visualize.

So this is one way to think about what's going on. Multiple regression gives you a bunch of partial slopes that tell you how much we think Y will increase if you increase a particular variable by one unit, but hold everything else constant.

Comment: You actually make very good points Mr Graham Especially how the Plane Equation Ax + By + Cz + d = 0 have it's coefficients A,B relating to partial slopes .