# Expression for OLS estimator in multivariate setting

Tags: econometrics

Assume that we have the following DGP:
$$
y=\beta_{1}+\beta_{2}X+\epsilon
$$
where $X=\{0,1\}$ is an indicator variable. The OLS estimator in
this case is easy to compute:
$$
\hat{\beta}_{OLS}=E\left[y|X=1\right]-E\left[y|X=0\right]
$$
Now assume that we have another continuous variable $Z.$ Write down
the DGP as
$$
y=\beta_{1}+\beta_{3}X+\beta_{4}Z+\epsilon
$$

In this case, can we write down the OLS estimator as:
$$
\hat{\beta}_{OLS}=E[E\left[y|X=1\right]-E\left[y|X=0\right]|Z]
$$

where we take the difference in conditional means of $y$ for $X=1$
and $X=0$ for each value of $Z,$ and then average over it?

Comment: If $Z$ is  continuous random variable, you may not have any observations with the same $Z$ and different $X$ so it is not clear what your final expression would then mean

Comment: Regress $(X,y)$ against $Z$ and then apply your first formula to the residuals.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/46508/919 for further explanation and software.

Comment: @Henry Of course, in which case their contribution to the estimate would be precisely 0. The only contributors to the slope coefficient would consist of those points where variation in X conditional on Z exists..

Comment: @Kwame Usually, like with your DGP where it's a simple constant slope, we make assumption about how $Z$ influences $Y$ (potentiality in interaction with $X$) and then use these assumptions to interpolate/extrapolate the missing matches.