Fitting against residuals equivalent to optimizing global linear model?
Suppose you are building linear models to optimize $r^2$ against a target variable $y.$ You have a current model $m$, and you are considering many candidate predictors $x_1, x_2, ..., x_{1000}$ to add to the model. The goal is to select the best single $x_i$ that makes the best addition to the current model in the form $\beta_m * m + \beta_i * x_i.$  Is this equivalent to choosing the $x_i$ that maximizes univariate $r^2$ on $y$ residualized against the current model $m$?
From poking around at the math, it seems like when you give yourself the free parameter $\beta_m$, the equivalence no longer holds. Yet this seems to be a common technique in things like gradient boosted trees. I believe typical random forest implementations will fix the weight of the current model at $1$, but this seems like a significant handicap. If you don't allow yourself to downweight the existing model, it seems that your search for the next predictor will be biased away from predictors that are strong but correlated and would add more value than a weak but uncorrelated predictor.

I'm not entirely clear about what your question is. Are you more interested in linear models (end of the first paragraph) or RFs/GBTs? And are you asking about picking the best single additional predictor, or a set of predictors?

Asking about picking the best single additional predictor. The question is easiest to analyze in the context of linear models: under what circumstances is the best additional predictor the one that maximizes r^2 to the target after residualization to the current model. I believe this only holds when you constrain the new model to be $m + \beta_i * x_i$ rather than allowing reweighting of the existing model.

I bring up GBTs as motivation for the question - GBTs are a practical context where iterative predictors are fit to residualized target, so it makes sense to ask if this is a reasonable objective. While GBTs are not considered linear models, they are still formed by adding up a bunch of trees linearly; if you consider each possible tree as a candidate predictor, then the analysis of linear model would apply.

Assuming by "$r^2$" you mean something related to the sum of squared residuals in a way that does not depend on the number of explanatory variables (it's not an adjusted r-squared, for instance), the short answer is yes.  It is explained in many posts here concerning computing least squares estimates in a stepwise fashion, such as https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46185.  Indeed, what you describe is one iteration in a forward stepwise regression procedure, extensively deprecated here: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=stepwise+regression+is%3Aanswer+score%3A4.

Extending what @whuber said in a comment:

Assuming by "$r^2$" you mean something related to the sum of squared residuals in a way that does not depend on the number of explanatory variables (it's not an adjusted r-squared, for instance), the short answer is yes.

That's a big problem when that approach is used in forward stepwise regression. It leads to risks of severe overfitting or missing other important predictors, as you recognize.
It's not such a problem for random forests and boosted trees, however. Those methods inherently minimize the risks of overfitting, if they are set up properly. Quoting from An Introduction to Statistical Learning, p. 352 (bold emphasis added):

In random forests, the trees are once again grown independently on random samples of the observations. However, each split on each tree is performed using a random subset of the features, thereby decorrelating the trees, and leading to a more thorough exploration of model space relative to bagging.
In boosting, we only use the original data, and do not draw any random samples. The trees are grown successively, using a “slow” learning approach: each new tree is fit to the signal that is left over from the earlier trees, and shrunken down before it is used.

In random forests, restricting to a random subset of features minimizes the problems with this approach. With boosted trees, the "shrinking" used in its "slow" learning approach minimizes the problems.
