# Making a Time-series Stationary: Order of Operations

Tags: time-series, stationarity, seasonality, trend

Following various sources including [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2077/how-to-make-a-time-series-stationary), which is the correct approach to making a time-series stationary?

1. Remove trend
2. Remove seasonality

**or**

1. Remove seasonality with estimated trend
2. Re-estimate trend from de-seasoned data
3. Remove trend

Comment: As always (after spending hours looking at various sources) as soon as I post a question I find the solution: This [link](http://au.mathworks.com/help/econ/seasonal-adjustment-using-snxd7m-seasonal-filters.html) explains how to do this in MatLab but the process is explained very clearly